# Wrong sequence for list using sorted()

Tags: python, sorting

I have some images which I generate from url with random pictures. Then I try to sort them to work with it properly, but they sorting is messed up. Appreciate any advices or pointing to what I missing

**Code ( *image list generating* ):**

```
def image_downloader():

    image_url = 'url'

    for count in tqdm(range(20)):
        image_data = requests.get(image_url).content

        with open(f'image_{count}.jpg', 'wb') as handler:
            handler.write(image_data)

        sleep(0.5)
```

**And my sorting ( trying to get it by generated picture "id" ):**

```
local_folder_content = os.listdir('.')

images_list = list((image for image in local_folder_content if image.endswith('.jpg')))

pprint((sorted(images_list, key=lambda x: x[:-4].split('_')[1])))
```

**Result( sorting is messed up) :**

```
['image_0.jpg',
 'image_1.jpg',
 'image_10.jpg',
 'image_11.jpg',
 'image_12.jpg',
 'image_13.jpg',
 'image_14.jpg',
 'image_15.jpg',
 'image_16.jpg',
 'image_17.jpg',
 'image_18.jpg',
 'image_19.jpg',
 'image_2.jpg',
 'image_3.jpg',
 'image_4.jpg',
 'image_5.jpg',
 'image_6.jpg',
 'image_7.jpg',
 'image_8.jpg',
 'image_9.jpg']
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Alderven there is no error, I just getting wrong sorting sequence

Comment: Your key function still returns a string, not an integer . `"19"` is not `19`.

Comment: When sorting strings, `10` legitimately comes before `2`.

Comment: As an aside, `list((image for image in local_folder_content if image.endswith('.jpg')))` should just be `[image for image in local_folder_content if image.endswith('.jpg'))]`

Comment: @chepner oh, okay miss this one, will try to int it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
images_list.sort(key= lambda i: int(i.lstrip('image_').rstrip('.jpg')))
```

Comment: Yeah, thats work perfectly mate, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate all filenames with two (or more) digits:

```
with open(f'image_{str(count).zfill(2)}.jpg', 'wb') as handler:
```

Output:

```
image_01.jpg
image_02.jpg
image_04.jpg
```

In this case your images will be correctly sorted.

Comment: If i generate more than 100 images it still get wrong sequence
`['image_00.jpg',
 'image_01.jpg',
 'image_02.jpg',
 'image_03.jpg',
 'image_04.jpg',
 'image_05.jpg',
 'image_06.jpg',
 'image_07.jpg',
 'image_08.jpg',
 'image_09.jpg',
 'image_10.jpg',
 'image_100.jpg',
 'image_101.jpg',
 'image_102.jpg',
 'image_103.jpg',
 'image_104.jpg',
 'image_105.jpg',
 'image_106.jpg',
 'image_107.jpg',
 'image_108.jpg',
 'image_109.jpg',
 'image_11.jpg',`

Comment: Change `zfill(2)` to `zfill(4)` and it will generates you `image_0001.jpg`